# Mongo DB query on oplog is failing even though document exists

Tags: mongodb, find, timestamp

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find( { }, { ts: 1} ).sort( {$natural : 1} ).limit(1)
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1403030678, 90) }
rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find({ "ts" :  Timestamp(1403030678, 90)}).count()
0
```

We have been peacefully using the mongo-connector until recently. We repaired our DB since then the mongo-connector is failing. On debugging we found that queries on oplog based on Timestamp are failing. We have simplified the query to a a direct match on 'ts' that was returned by find. Surprisingly mongo fails to find the document it just returned.
Any suggestions on what might be going on?
We are using mongo db 2.4.6.

We looked at this [MongoDB Cannot find entry by specifing ts.t(ts is a Timestamp type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360404/mongodb-cannot-find-entry-by-specifing-ts-tts-is-a-timestamp-type) to make sure our query was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically hitting this: [Index on ts field in oplog.rs is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389325/index-on-ts-field-in-oplog-rs-is-not-updated)

mongodb replication uses a special optimized method to insert data into the oplog capped collection. Part of the optimization is that it doesn't update any indexes on the collection.

Comment: Which is a perfect way to slow literally everything down in a RS. The index isn't there for fun or just because.